# Layout collides with a variable or import in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

Below is my xml where its giving me a warning.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:tag="xlarge">

        .......

    </RelativeLayout>

</Layout>
```

Dont know what is the issue? and where its showing me that warning. But would love any help how it can be resolved. Tried searching for it on internet but couldn't find anything helpful.

Below is the warning that i am getting...

```
ERROR: View field thirdPartyLayout collides with a variable or import
```

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: Hi, updated my question.. added warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the issue with your layout. It has something to do with `thirdPartyLayout`. Kindly check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817130/java-the-import-collides-with-another-import-statement). Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: well thanks for the link, the issue is similar but havent yet figured out what was wrong with my issue. But thanks for sending me atleast gave me an idea.

Answer (score 17):

This could happen if your variable name conflicts with an ID tag, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="thirdPartyLayout"
            type="String" />
    </data>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thirdPartyLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</layout>
```

Resolution: rename one of them.

Comment: Thanks! This advice solved my problem from another topic. This real problem is reported while running gradle task `:app:kaptDebugKotlin`. However this important `ERROR: View field NAME collides with a variable or import` is report as _warning_ . If we miss this message, we may get another error (e.g. `Cannot find symbol DataBindingComponent`) on `:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac` stage.