# Making a code more readable

Tags: java, readability

I have two classes in my app with identicall names, I cannot rename them, on of them is from packageA second from packageB, the name of this class is State, and I have to use it in one place in my program like this:

```
 Map<Integer,Set<org.omg.PortableServer.POAManagerPackage.State>>
```

is there any way (but using this class) to make this somewhat more readable(to shorten it somewhat)?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447880/change-name-of-import-in-java-or-import-two-classes-with-the-same-name

Comment: Today I learned: you can't statically import a package, only a type. That was going to be my suggestion

Answer (score 4):

Possibly derive from one of the classes to disambiguate. For example, in `POAState.java`:

```
import org.omg.PortableServer.POAManagerPackage.State;

public class POAState extends State {}
```

then:

```
Map<Integer,Set<POAState>> my_map;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create wrapping class that will have only `Set<org.omg.PortableServer.POAManagerPackage.State>` and all the needed `Set` methods.

usage in client:

```
Map<Integer,GoodWrappingSetName>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the two different `State` classes in the same piece of code (*.java file), then the answer is "No", Java does not provide a short hand notation. You must be explicit and include the full package names to remove the ambiguity.

@dantuch has raised an interesting idea, but rather than wrap the class, if you can extend one of them, you can create an empty sub-class of `State` that simply defers all of it's implementation to the parent class.

```
public MyState extends State {
    // no implementation required
}
```

Then you can then refer to MyState