# Why would a module in a JAR not be found?

Tags: java, python, netbeans-7, jython, worldwind

I am working in NetBeans 7 with Python script using Jython.  I am trying to build a NASA WorldWind example.

I have added JARs to the classpath, including the one that contains gov.nasa.worldwind.

The code crashes, saying

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wrightky\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WW\src\ww.py", line 4, in <module>
  import gov.nasa.worldwind as wwj
  ImportError: No module named gov
```

I have both added the JAR with "gov" to the classpath and even added the JAR to the Python package manually, under which I can see gov.nasa.worldwind.

I could add my code but not sure if it's relevant.

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem in Eclipse, and I am not sure of the analogous solution in NetBeans though it isn't important to me at this point.  Simply importing a JAR file is not enough to claim its functionality.  It must be added to the Interpreter Libraries.

Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter - Jython -> New Folder (I did New Jar/Zip(s) as well, I assume either would solve the issue) and point to the directory (or JAR).

Answer (score 1):

From your question it's not entirely clear whether you're compiling a Java class file or something from Python, but if it is Java you should know that you can't do `import X as Y` in Java.  If you have conflicting class names, you'll just have to always use the fully-qualified class name (ie `gov.nasa.wordwind.SomeClass`) every time you reference it.

See this question for more details:
[Change Name of Import in Java, or import two classes with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447880/change-name-of-import-in-java-or-import-two-classes-with-the-same-name)

Comment: The code is Python, but needs to use Java libraries and WorldWind JARs.  I will try your suggestion, though.

Comment: Upon removing the 'as Y' and replacing Y with X, I get the same error, that gov, a package within an imported JAR, cannot be found.

Comment: unfortunately I'm a Java guy, lacking much knowledge of python.  Hopefully somebody more knowledgeable in the ways of Python will be able to help you out.  Sorry my suggestion didn't help.

Comment: Yes.  I wasn't sure what to attribute this error to, Python or Java.  Thanks for the suggestion.