# Address a Package name by a shorter name

Tags: java, namespaces, package

I have arranged my .java files in a folder-subfolder-* structure. My initial package name is (e.g)

```
com.company.app
```

Therefore the .java files in a would have a namespace / package of

```
com.company.app.folder1.folder2
```

And to access any of the classes from the **com.company.app** I have to prefix the class name with the package name.

```
com.company.app.Game
```

I was wondering if there is a way to set an alias or a pointer to a package(name) and then be able to just use the pointer ?

like so

```
app.Game
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Name of Import in Java, or import two classes with the same name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447880/change-name-of-import-in-java-or-import-two-classes-with-the-same-name)

Comment: Hmmm. That would be importing a .java only. I would like to refer to the package name directly.

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by `refer`?

Comment: Sure. I would like to be able to refer to a class as "app.Game" instead of "com.company.app.Game"

Comment: If you are not importing, then you must explicitly put the qualified name. As of Java 8 it doesn't support alias resolution.

Comment: Yeah. Thought as much. Wishful thinking I guess. Thanks though !