# Java - use two classes with equal name

Tags: java

Is there a possibility, to use two classes which have got equal class names not having to directly specify from which package one of them comes from?

For example:

```
using com.org.TreeView;

...
TreeView tv = new TreeView();
reg.org.TreeView tvOrg = new reg.org.TreeView();
```

I don't want to every time specify that the other `TreeView` comes from `reg.org`.

What I would like to do is, to specify some variable, which takes the type of the `reg.org.TreeView` and every time I need to create the `reg.org.TreeView` I use this variable and not to whole type. Using the full path of the class can be annoying when the package root is huge.

Comment: A decorator might work

Comment: Check this question, it answers it perfectly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447880/change-name-of-import-in-java-or-import-two-classes-with-the-same-name

Comment: @JosepPrat:  Java isn't Python.

Comment: My first thought was to write a subclass that extends `TreeView` (assuming it isn't `final`), and rewrite all the constructors using `super(...)`.    There's still a problem if any of the public methods take `reg.org.TreeView` parameters, or return `reg.org.TreeView` results.  If that isn't a problem, then you get the methods for free.  (Except static methods.)

Comment: Well, let's back up a step.  How do you have a scenario in which you can have ambiguous class names?  Is this a code smell indicating that you should probably consolidate responsibilities somewhere?

Comment: @Makoto how do you know _he_'s responsible for those class names?  I run into this problem when using other people's libraries.

Comment: @ajb:  I *don't* know, which is why I'm asking.  To your point about third-party libraries sometimes introducing this:  yes, that's true, but a layer of abstraction can solve that particular case should that be necessary.

Comment: @Makoto please read the question I linked, they ask if a feature is available in Java. Casually this feature is qualified imports, which casually Python has.
The question linked is about Java

Answer (score -3):

not because it is ambiguous, you have to specify the class package.

Comment: ummm, I think he already knows that, he's asking if there's a way around it.