# Alias a Java class from nested namespaces

Tags: java

I have a Java class that is located here:

```
package suman;

public class Output {
 public static class foo {
   public static class PUT {
     public static interface basic {
       public static class req {
         public static class Body {   // namespaced class "Body"
           String foo = "bar";
           int bar = 5;
           boolean zoom = false;
         }
       }
     }

  }
}
```

I use it like so:

```
import static suman.Output.foo;

public class FooImplementer {

  public void bar(){
    foo.PUT.basic.req.Body x = new foo.PUT.basic.req.Body()
  }
}
```

However, that's a lot of characters, I am looking for a way to alias it somehow. The only way I can think of aliasing it, is to use a private class, something like this:

```
class Body extends foo.PUT.basic.req.Body {
     private JsonObject(){}
}
```

and I can use it like so:

```
   public void bar(){
       Body x = new Body()
    }
```

is there perhaps another way to do this?

Comment: If your actual model require such many nested class, change your model ;)

Comment: Just import the class and use its simple name. `import suman.Output.foo.PUT.basic.req.Body;`...`Body x = new Body();`

Comment: @azro I wish, but this one file has many types in it, so a lot of nested things in one file

Answer (score 4):

Just use a normal import:

```
import suman.Output.foo.PUT.basic.req.Body;

public class FooImplementer {
    public void bar(){
        Body x = new Body();
    }
}
```

Comment: *static* imports, not normal imports.

Comment: It would be `import static suman.Output.foo.PUT.basic.req.Body`, since they are static classes.

Comment: I actually don't understand static imports if someone wants to explain it lol

Comment: @AlexanderMills This has nothing to do with static imports. Static imports are for importing static members of another class so you don't have to prefix them with the class name.

Comment: this won't work well if there are multiple classes called Body, that's my problem

Comment: @AlexanderMills Then how would extending it help?

Comment: I think his idea of extending would allow for aliasing say `a.long.Body` and `another.long.Body` into two shorter names, not necessarily called `Body`. @AlexanderMills [Java does not provide import aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32537545/5623232), unfortunately.

Comment: is there really no way to create a type alias?

Comment: There really isn't.

Comment: Extending the class is just for aliasing. But in this case I would want to prevent any new members being added to the subclass but using Java theres no annotation of feature that could prevent a subclass from adding new members/fields.